# SQL SELECT exclude child if parent is present

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a `Projects` table where projects can be nested by `projectA.parent_id = projectB.id`.

When selecting all projects that meet a given criteria, how can we select **only** the parent if both meet it (or the parent meets it) and **only** the child if the child meets it?

| id | parent_id | is_chosen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | false |
| 2 | 1 | true |
| 3 | 2 | true |
| 4 | 1 | false |
| 5 | 4 | false |
| 6 | 1 | false |
| 7 | 6 | true |
| 8 | 1 | true |
| 9 | 8 | false |

```sql
SELECT p.id 
FROM "Projects" p
JOIN "Projects" parent
ON p.parent_id = p.id
WHERE is_chosen = true
  AND ...
```

The result should be `2,7,8` and not `2,3,7,8`. `3` would be excluded because its parent `2` was selected.

What should be included in the `AND` to accomplish this, or should it be restructured?

Comment: Doesn't that give an ambiguous column error?

Comment: Should than not be joining on `parent.id`........?

Comment: I suppose the query should be universal in terms that it should return the correct results for both conditions `is_chosen = false` and `is_chosen = true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can union two queries, one for the parents, one for the children. For example:

```
select distinct *
from (
  select p.* -- finding parents
  from projects p
  join projects c on c.parent_id = p.id
  where p.is_chosen
 union all
  select c.* -- finding children
  from projects p
  join projects c on c.parent_id = p.id
  where not p.is_chosen and c.is_chosen
) x
```

Result:

```
 id  parent_id  is_chosen 
 --- ---------- --------- 
 2   1          t         
 8   1          t         
 7   6          t
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2404d16f82127c24000057bae583cad8).

Comment: This looks great. In reality our WHERE clause is quite complex. Is there a way to factor it out of the union for reuse across both select statements?

Comment: Added as a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72822272/sql-select-refactor-and-reuse-complex-where-clause

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to simplify to this:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM parents p
WHERE is_chosen = 'true'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM parents p2
                WHERE p2.is_chosen = 'true'
                AND p2.id = p.parent_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE like this

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tab 
    WHERE is_chosen
)
SELECT
    id
FROM CTE t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE id = t.parent_id
)
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3ca23673693a3bb16ae56a71dfd8c5d4)