# SQL Select refactor and reuse complex where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

We're doing the following union, which re-uses the where clause in 3 places:

```sql
select distinct *
from (
  select p.* -- finding parents
  from projects p
  join projects c on c.parent_id = p.id
  where p.is_chosen
 union all
  select c.* -- finding children
  from projects p
  join projects c on c.parent_id = p.id
  where not p.is_chosen and c.is_chosen
) x
```

Now we want to add a more complex where clause instead of `is_chosen`.

Is there a way to factor out the where clause so that it can be reused in all 3 places?

For example, how would we simplify:

```sql
select distinct *
from (
  select p.* -- finding parents
  from projects p
  join projects c on c.parent_id = p.id
  where p.is_chosen and p.last_active > now() - interval '7' day and (select count(*) from items i where i.project_id = p.id and i.last_active is not null) > 5
 union all
  select c.* -- finding children
  from projects p
  join projects c on c.parent_id = p.id
  where not (p.is_chosen and p.last_active > now() - interval '7' day and (select count(*) from items i where i.project_id = p.id and i.last_active is not null) > 5) and (c.is_chosen and c.last_active > now() - interval '7' day and (select count(*) from items i where i.project_id = c.id and i.last_active is not null) > 5)
) x
```

We've tried a `WITH` clause at the beginning, unsuccessfully.

Comment: can child project be a parent project too ?

Comment: Good question -- no it cannot

Comment: reuse only for sake of reuse can be hard..  if we treat 7 and 5 as parameters, this can be elevated to `WITH params as (.... ) `  and reused in multiple places.  Join in first query can be replaced with `and exists` and distinct in outer query is redundant in this case

Distinct looks redundant if project can be only parent or child but not both.

Comment: If you add a sample data and desired results it would be much easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to reformulare your question

You need to get all `projects` for which `is_chosen = TRUE` and `last_active` is no older than 7 days, that have more than 5 rows in `items` table  with `last_active IS NOT NULL`. The query must exclude child projects if parent is in the results.

If it is so, than you can use a CTE like this

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT p.*
    FROM projects p
    WHERE 
    (
        p.parent_id IS NOT NULL -- project is a child
        OR EXISTS (
            -- project should have some children
            SELECT FROM projects WHERE parent_id = p.id
        )  
    )
    -- other conditions 
    AND p.is_chosen 
    AND p.last_active > now() - interval '7' day
    AND (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM items i 
        WHERE i.project_id = p.id 
              AND i.last_active IS NOT NULL
    ) > 5
)
SELECT *
FROM cte t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    -- do not include child if parent presents
    SELECT FROM cte WHERE id = t.parent_id 
)
```

Please, check [a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4e7265d43e3c53f938ce9ed7eff04437) with modified sample data from your previous querstion.

Comment: Not quite -- the query should include a child if its parent is not present in the result, and only the parent if both are present.

Comment: I meant it off course. I'll edit formulation. Query does what you say

Comment: And, from first JOIN.. query should include only parents with one or more children

Comment: @Kadet, thank you for hint, I missed that.

Comment: @Tyler, I've updated the query, added missing children existence condition. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, is this select below give same results ?

```
select p.* from projects p
left join projects parent on (p.parent_id = parent.id)
where p.is_chosen 
  and p.last_active > now() - interval '7' day 
  and (select count(*) from items i where i.project_id = p.id and i.last_active is not null) > 5
and (
  p.parent_id is null and exists (select 1 from projects where parent_id = p.id )
  or 
  p.parent_id is not null and not (parent.is_chosen 
       and parent.last_active > now() - interval '7' day 
       and (select count(*) from items i where i.project_id = parent.id and i.last_active is not null) > 5
  )
)
```